# Is the nesting network in one machine correct?

Tags: subnet

My colleague configured the following three networks list this (Each machine has three NICs):

eth0: 192.168.0.0/16

eth1: 10.10.0.0/16

eth2: 10.0.0.0/8

I suggest to change eth1 to 172.16.0.0/16 but he think his previous configuration is correct. I was wondering if the configuration is correct. If it is not, what is the disadvantage?

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that two of the interfaces have overlapping networks. This will cause confusion in the OS. Only one of the interfaces will be used for traffic destined to the overlap of the interfaces. For example, this could cause a response to incoming requests from `10.10.0.1` (one of the 65,534 usable addresses which could overlap) on `eth2` to be sent to `eth1`, and the requesting host will never get a response.

Answer (score 0):

eth 2

Address:   10.0.0.0
Netmask:   255.0.0.0 = 8
Wildcard:  0.255.255.255
=>
Network:   10.0.0.0/8
Broadcast: 10.255.255.255
HostMin:   10.0.0.1
HostMax:   10.255.255.254
Hosts/Net: 16777214

eth 1

Address:   10.10.0.0
Netmask:   255.255.0.0 = 16
Wildcard:  0.0.255.255
=>
Network:   10.10.0.0/16
Broadcast: 10.10.255.255
HostMin:   10.10.0.1
HostMax:   10.10.255.254
Hosts/Net: 65534

Both are conflicting.